# MySQL; get all cards & all decks associated for each cards in one request

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I want to be able to see each decks where a card is and display it as following.
A card can be in multiple decks. And there will be many cards/decks.
The server is in php.

```
|List of cards|   In decks        |
|-------------|-------------------|
|CardA        |DeckA, DeckC       |
|CardB        |DeckC, DeckF, DeckY|
|CardC        |                   |
```

The database as is:

```
CREATE TABLE `card` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `deck` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `deck_card` (
  `deck_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `card_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (deck_id, card_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (card_id) REFERENCES card(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (deck_id) REFERENCES deck(id)
);
```

I want to avoid having to do a request for each card.
Is there a way to request all the cards and each associated deck in one request using MySQL?

Comment: Your api call to your db can return any and everything you need it to. .... Do you have any code to show other than this data structure?

Comment: Use join + group_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next simple query can solve your problem:

```
SELECT 
    `c`.`name` `card_name`,
    COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(`d`.`name`),'') `deck_names`
FROM `card` `c`
LEFT JOIN `deck_card` `dc` ON `c`.`id` = `dc`.`card_id`
LEFT JOIN `deck` `d` ON `d`.`id` = `dc`.`deck_id`
GROUP BY `c`.`name`
;
```

Result from [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=28b22fd52da22aac7923cb78f2f31b6f&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

```
+===========+=============+
| card_name | deck_names  |
+===========+=============+
| CardA     | DeckA,DeckB |
+-----------+-------------+
| CardB     | DeckC,DeckE |
+-----------+-------------+
| CardC     |             |
+-----------+-------------+
```